# Excel formula to split file path in columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

This is my file path:

```
/Adobe/work/5.practices/5.1 Students/Reporting/studentReports/Ali's report/aliResult.pdf
```

Now I want split them in columns like shown below:

```
+-------+------+-------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+---------------+ 
| Adobe | work | 5.practices | 5.1 Students | Reporting | studentReports | Ali's report | aliResult.pdf |
```

Comment: Does it need to be a formula? You could you use the Text-to-column, setting the delimiter to "/"

Comment: @Moacir, that's a great, simple solution.  Why don't you post an answer?  Even if it turns out to not meet the OP's requirements, it could be a good solution for other readers.

Comment: @fixer1234 Done :)

Comment: # Rehana, Do you need comma as suffix after been separated? If not  edit the post.

Answer (score 5):

There is a tool in the `Data` tab in Excel that you may be able to use, called [Text-To-Columns](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7).

- Select the cell with the data.
- Select `Text to Columns` in the Data tab.
- Choose the delimiter as "OTHER", and insert the character you want it to use as the split condition. In this case, the "/" (without quotes) or any other character you want to use.

With this, Excel will split the text in multiple columns for you in one step, and without the need for formulas.

BTW, you don't need to do this one cell at a time.  You can select the whole column, do one Text to Columns operation, and Excel will do the entire list in one step.

Comment: I think the request for a "formula" wasn't necessarily meant literally.  :-)

Comment: But OP  needs to separate them in columns with Comma as suffix

Comment: @fixer1234, OP needs comma as Suffix while separate them.

Comment: @RajeshS Thats the "other" part I mentioned. You can define which is the delimiter. It doesnt need to be a Comma

Comment: I can vouch this works because I used this tool extensively. Used also for "|", for example, where the values between the pipes had commas in it. So it could NOT separate the commas

Comment: @Moacir,, check this 1: Adobe, 2: Work, where Adobe & others followed by Comma !

Comment: @RajeshS, I think the commas were inserted only because the OP wrote it as a list in a sentence.  I doubt the OP requires the commas.

Comment: @fixer1234, Original post has comma between and OP demanded Formula. So that I'm sure has Comma as suffix. Let  the OP decide ☺

Comment: OP says *I want split them in column**s***. "Column**S**", not "column". So I think this solution is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use formulas too, but I highly recommend Text to Columns.

If your main string is in `A1`, put this in `A2` and drag right:

```
=COLUMN()&". "&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A$1,"/",REPT(" ",99)),(COLUMN()+1)*99-98,99))
```

<sub>This answer shamelessly lifted from [Rick Rothstein on this Forum](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/798960-extract-string-between-second-third-forward-slashes.html)</sub>

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**This simple UDF will spli & place values in Columns:**

```
Function SplitValues(a As String, b As String)
  Dim Text() As String
  Text = Split(b, a)
  SplitValues = Text
End Function
```

**How it works:**

1. Write this array formula then fill Right and 
   press `F2` & finish with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.

   `{=SplitValues("/",A2)}`

**Note:**

1. Cell A6 will be blank because the Text starts with "/".
2. Cell `A2` has text to be spited.
3. Adjust cell references in formula as needed.